# Properties panel content gone

Tags: modeling

[image]

Where did the stuff in properties panel go?

Comment: Hi. Please expand on which specific 'stuff' you are referring to. You can add more details to your question by using the [edit] link below it.

Answer (score 1):

[image: New Locations of Toolbar Content]

The Properties Panel in your screenshot is simply retracted. I marked the arrow that expands it. Some of its previous options can also be found in the Tool Tab, also marked.

On top of the Outliner, top right of your image, there is also a dropdown menu that contains some of what before was in the tool panel.